# Calling extended class function from parent class

Tags: php, oop, class, function

I'm new to OO PHP. Got some questions.

```
class a {
   protected function a1() {
      ...
   }
}

class b extends a {
   public function b1() {
      ...
   }
}
```

Let's say we have 2 classes like explained above. I'm calling b's method like example below

```
class a {
   var $b;
   function __construct()
   {
      $b = new b();
   }
   protected function a1() {
      $b->b1();    
    }
}

class b extends a {
   public function b1() {
      ...
   }
}
```

I know that, it's possible to call parent class'es method from extended class, but I wonder if reverse way is possible? I mean, calling extended classes method from inside parent class (in this case, `class b`'s method from `class a`) without declaring in `__contruct`, simply by `$this->b()`;?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can call a method in the extending class.

```
<?php
class a 
{
    public function a1 ()
    {
        $this->b1();    
    }
    
    protected function b1()
    {
        echo 'This is in the a class<br />';
    }
}

class b extends a 
{
    protected function b1()
    {
        echo 'This is in the b class<br />';
    }
}

class c extends a
{
    protected function b1()
    {
        echo 'This is in the c class<br />';
    }
}

$a = new a();
$a->a1();

$b = new b();
$b->a1();

$c = new c();
$c->a1();   
?>
```

This will result in:

> This is in the a class 
> This is in the b class 
> This is in the c class

You may also be interested in abstract classes https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Answer (score 4):

use Magic methods of PHP `__call` or `__callStatic`

[`Reference`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)